# Run two processes/apps in the same Dalvik VM

Tags: android, dalvik

Is it possible to run two processes/apps in the same Dalvik VM (instance)?

Answer (score 6):

Two apps can specify that they want to [share the same process](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#proc) in their manifest, but this is only allowed if they are signed with the same key.

Comment: Is it means then that they are running on the same Dalvik VM?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that is possible, Each app is assigned its own Dalvik Machine.

Comment: So I know ActivityManagerService send an intent to zygote to start a new activity/process. If I would edit this intent, can it be possible to start then my second app in the same Dalvik VM